# Protege: Excel / csv to rdf conversion

Tags: csv, rdf, protege4

I have created a Family ontology, and now I want to convert the data in csv into rdf using the ontology, plz correct if I am wrong, how can I do this ?
The Excel Import utility of Protege is no longer supported !
I am using Protege 4.3

Comment: There's no single way to convert RDF data into CSV/tabular data.  I'd guess that you're looking to do something like having a row for each of a number of individuals, and have a column for each of a number of properties, but this isn't at all clear from your question.  Please show a sample of the RDF data that you have, and a sample of the CSV you'd like to obtain.  It's probably not too hard to do such a construction with SPARQL.

Comment: I want to convert CSV to RDF, I have created a Family Ontology, so how can I relate it to the csv / map it to the columns of csv so that it will create rdf with logically correct Subject Predicate Objects ?

Comment: That should be much easier, but without seeing your ontology or data, we can't really say much more than that.

Comment: Ok but how ? Can you plz suggest a tool ? thanks for your help